# Using a mesh collider in Unity with Bullet Physics

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, bulletphysics, collider

When using this ramp as a collider with Convex Hull the ball rolls on the edge like this:

**Ramp and ball**

[image: Ramp and ball]

**Bullet physics settings**

[image: Bullet physics settings]

**Blender**

[image: Blender]

Thanks!

/T

Comment: thats concave, not convex

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Because that is not a convex shape.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The creator of the plugin gave this solution to the shape:

- approximate the shape with multiple simple colliders (boxes)
- use BVHTriangleMeshShape if it is static
- use the GImpactTriangleMeshShape if it is dynamic